# Defining array of unknown type of objects and assign the correct type of objects in the constructor

Tags: java, generics, vector, arraylist

I am trying to achieve generic behavior of foo_unknown class, which calls foo_func1(), foo_func2() methods; and it depends on the type of objects defined in the constructor of foo class that which foo_func1() and foo_func2() method implementations are called. 
Any new revolutionary design pattern is welcome too. Which takes care of all the issues.

Comment: You're really going to have to clarify what you're trying to do. What is the exact problem you're having with your code? Do you understand what an Interface does in Java? That also seems like it might be the problem.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to define abstract foo_func1 and foo_func2 in a base class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. I know about interfaces. I am implementing a Genetic algorithm. The class foo1 and foo2 are say different domain of problems. foo_controller is the Genetic algorithm class that calls different functions in foo1(crossover, fitness) and foo2 classes. So you are suggesting to define an interface foo and assign that foo as field in foo_controller while foo1 and foo2 implement that interface. Good suggesting I will try that.

Comment: From what you are describing here it sounds like you wish to implement the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexander. If you are suggesting me to create foo1 and foo2 as abstract classes which are extended by foo. While I call foo_func1() and foo_func2(), then both foo1 and foo2 classes will have different implementations of foo_func1() and foo_func2() causing a conflict since I cannot extend both foo1 and foo2, also there can be N number of foo1, foo2, .. fooN(rightnow N=5). Else, if you are suggesting to create foo as abstract class, then I think I won't be able to instantiate foo as a field of foo_controller.

Comment: `foo` should be abstract, with the two abstract methods. This does not forbid using `foo` as a variable type in your controller. Of course you can't then create directly objects of foo, but you don't need those anyway, you always would have either foo1 or foo2 objects in these variables.

Comment: By the way, the usual convention is to use capitalized names for classes, and lower-case only for methods and (non-static-final) variables. (And if you want to answer to a specific person, include '@ name', like '@pulkittomar' in the responding comment. Then they are automatically notified.)

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann I usually do similar implementations with function pointers in C. I am not very good with java. Your suggestion will work by defining dummy abstract class. In my previous work I was using foo for defining some sub operations common to all problem domains, like converting float implementation of chromosome string to decimal value, thus, I will have to create another dummy class. Right now I am reading for a more refined approach using generics/vector/Arraylist and strategy pattern suggested by @flippe. I will post the solution once I have an approach which I think works best.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not averse to doing this reflectively, try something like this:

```
public FooController(Class<? extends Foo> clazz, int number) {
     this.fooUnknown = Array.newInstance(clazz, number);
     for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
         Array.set(this.fooUnknown, i, clazz.newInstance());
     }
}
```

(Warning: not compiled, not tested, requires exception handling, etc)

Comment: Thanks, I am implementing the approach now. I will try that.

Comment: why not just `this.fooUnknown[i] = clazz.newInstance();`